# How do I enable a button after a video ends.?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that contains a video and a button, but i don't want the user to be able to click finish until the video ends.

Code for the video:

```
<video width="100%" height="480" controls>
    <source src="video/lesson4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Code for the finish button:

```
<form method="POST" action="week.php">
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn" name="register_btn" disabled="disabled"><h6>FINISH</h6></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should listen to "ended" event, like so:

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var button = document.getElementById("myButton")
video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
   button.disabled = false;
}, true);
```

See media events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**JavaScript**

```
var element = document.getElementById('video_id');

element.onended = function() {
     document.getElementById('btn').disabled = false;
};
```

**jQuery**

```
$("video").on("ended", function (e) {
    $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Same you can use for events play and pause.

For more events you can refer this: https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener 
Like this:

```
<video width="100%" height="480" controls>
<source src="video/lesson4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<form method="POST" action="week.php">
<div class="input-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn" name="register_btn"  class=“enableIfFinish”
disabled="disabled"><h6>FINISH</h6></button>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        $(‘.enableIfFinished’).prop(‘disabled’,false);
    }
</script>
```

Do not forget to include jquery library

Answer (score 0):

Following is working example

```js
document.getElementById('someID').addEventListener('ended',videoEndHandler,false);
function videoEndHandler(e) {
   document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<video id="someID" width="100%" height="480" controls>
    <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<form method="POST" action="week.php">
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="myBtn" name="register_btn" disabled="disabled"><h6>FINISH</h6></button>
    </div>
</form>
```